# client object model - disable event firing

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to disable event firing when doing a list item update from the Managed Client Object Model?

In the server model, I do the below. However, I cannot find a way of doing the same on the Managed Client ObjectModel:

```
class DisabledEventsScope : SPItemEventReceiver, IDisposable
        {          // Boolean to hold the original value of the EventFiringEnabled property        
            bool _originalValue;
            public DisabledEventsScope()
            {
                // Save off the original value of EventFiringEnabled              
                _originalValue = base.EventFiringEnabled;
                // Set EventFiringEnabled to false to disable it              
                base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            }
            public void Dispose()
            {
                // Set EventFiringEnabled back to its original value               
                base.EventFiringEnabled = _originalValue;
            }
        }

 using (DisabledEventsScope scope = new DisabledEventsScope())
                        {                            
                            // State-changing operation occurs here.
                            spItem.Update();
                        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do it in client object model, see the MSDN documentation on the SP.List object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554951. But you can develop custom web service which will be called from a client side and disable events' firing.